# Forum or Forums?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

When do I use "forum" versus "forums"? Some websites are using "forum", but some others use "forums".

- https://forum.joomla.org
- https://forums.linuxmint.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either can be used.

A [**forum**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum) deals with one topic whereas the word **forums** is used to group each forum together.

Incidentally there are people (sometimes highly educated but more often just pains in the necks) who prefer the "original" plural form in Latin: [**fora**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forum_%28Roman%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can use either word. In the first case, *forum* is probably used because the topic is always Joomla, although there are *sub-forums*, one for each orange header. In the second case, they preferred seeing the *sub-forums* as separated forums, and use the plural.

On Drupal.org, the URL for the forums is `https://drupal.org/forum`, although they are referred as *forums*, when somebody posts an issue about their own sites in the [Drupal.org webmasters queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters) and they are suggested to ask in the forums.